# Is it possible to create a database without a transaction log?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I was recently told that it is possible to create a new database in SQL Server without a transaction log.  I've worked with SQL Server for a very long time and I've never seen it done and I didn't think it was possible. I've gone over the Microsoft docs for the "CREATE DATABASE" syntax and couldn't find anything about it, but I can be blind sometimes and may have missed it.

Can one create a database without a transaction log?  If so, can someone point me at the documentation?

To be clear, I'm not talking about attaching a database with a log.  I know one can attach a database with a transaction log.  I'm also not talking about log backups.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Attaching files from an existing database is possible without the transaction log file(s) if the database was cleanly shut down and was writeable at the same.

This is documented at:

- [`CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH [ WITH < attach_database_option > ]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql#create-database--for-attach--with--attach_database_option--)

  > If a read/write database has a single log file that is currently unavailable, and if the database was shut down with no users or open transactions before the attach operation, FOR ATTACH automatically rebuilds the log file and updates the primary file.
- and [`FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql#for-attach_rebuild_log)

  > If one or more transaction log files are missing, the log file is rebuilt. The ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG automatically creates a new, 1-MB log file. This file is placed in the default log-file location.

...on the `CREATE DATABASE` page.

This is probably the context for what you were told.

As the documentation above makes clear, the engine builds a new log file for you. A running database always has a transaction log.

Answer (score 2):

#### Answering Your Questions

> **Can one create a database without a transaction log?**

If you semi-create a database with the SSMS GUI and before you click on OK you hit the **Script** button, it will create the following script:

```
CREATE DATABASE [NoTLOGDatabase]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'NoTLOGDatabase', FILENAME = N'E:\MSSQL16.GENERAL\MSSQL\DATA\NoTLOGDatabase.mdf' , SIZE = 65536KB , FILEGROWTH = 16384KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'NoTLOGDatabase_log', FILENAME = N'F:\MSSQL16.GENERAL\MSSQL\DATA\NoTLOGDatabase_log.ldf' , SIZE = 65536KB , FILEGROWTH = 16384KB )
 WITH LEDGER = OFF
GO
```

If you delete the part for the transaction log:

```
...
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'NoTLOGDatabase_log', FILENAME = N'F:\MSSQL16.GENERAL\MSSQL\DATA\NoTLOGDatabase_log.ldf' , SIZE = 65536KB , FILEGROWTH = 16384KB )
...
```

and then run the script you are presented with the following information:

> Completion time: 2023-10-17T15:31:32.9566292+02:00

This seems like a database was created without a TLOG file.

However, if you check the default location for TLOG files (the path can be found in the SQL Server properties), then you will notice that a TLOG file has been created, even though you did not specifically define the file.

**ANSWER** No, it is not possible to create a SQL Server database without a transaction log file.

> **If so, can someone point me at the documentation?**

No documentation available.